# Calculate a monthly uncertainty from an annual uncertainty

Tags: normal-distribution, uncertainty

Given a normal distribution of annual mean values (sunny days per year), I know the P50 and the annual uncertainty.

Is there any method to calculate the monthly uncertainty? Thank you very much.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "uncertainty"?  But whatever you mean, if you have only annual figures the answer is almost certainly "no", because of the (literally) seasonal effects.